# Linked list find function in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I've been working on a linked list which was implemented by the name vector_string.
I'm trying to insert words into it, if the word is already existed in the linked list, skip it.

```
void vector_string_insert(vector_string *vs, char *key) {
  vs_entry_t *newNode = (vs_entry_t*)malloc(sizeof(vs_entry_t));
  newNode->value = key;
  newNode->next = NULL;

  vs_entry_t *current = vs->head;

  if(vs->head == NULL)
  {
    vs->head = newNode;
  }
  else{
    while(current->next != NULL)
      current = current->next;

    current->next = newNode;
  }
}

bool vector_string_find(vector_string *vs, char *key) 
{
  vs_entry_t *current = vs->head;

  while(current != NULL)
  {
    if (current->value == key)
      return true;

    current = current->next;
  }
  return false;   
}
```

And here's my main:

```
  if (vector_string_find(header, "Hello") == false);
    vector_string_insert(header,"Hello");
  if (vector_string_find(header, "Hello") == false);
    vector_string_insert(header,"Hello");
  if (vector_string_find(header, "Hola") == false);
    vector_string_insert(header,"Hola");
```

Although the vector_string_find() returned "true" for the second "Hello", it still got inserted in the linked list:

```
1. Hello
2. Hello
3. Hola
```

Comment: Remove these trailing semicolons `if (...);` == `if (...) {}`.

Comment: thank you so much... I've been stuck on this for a whole. Only because of that.

Comment: You can't compare strings with `if (current->value == key)`. This just compares addresses and _not_ the string characters. Replace with: `if (strcmp(current->value, key) == 0)`

Comment: Consider merging these two functions so that `insert()` simply disregards any attempt to insert a duplicate (perhaps returning a value to indicate duplicate has been ignored.) Don't write **more** code; write **smarter** code.